# VIM Key bindings for Adobe Flash Builder 4

Tags: apache-flex, vim, flash-builder

I was curious if anyone knew of a way to get VI/VIM key bindings in Flash Builder 4.  I know that I can just edit the files in VIM directly, but as I am just getting started in Flex - I would prefer to use the IDE until I get my feet about me.

I am running Flash Builder 4 on OSX Snow Leopard.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't used Flash Builder 4, but I am under the impression it is basically a plugin for the Eclipse IDE.  If this is the case, then the easiest way to get Vim key bindings might be to install the Vrapper plugin.  The site for the plugin is: http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/home/

- The site provides links that can be
  used within Eclipse to install the
  plugin.  I'd probably start with this
  one:
  http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/update-site/stable
- To install the plugin from within the
  IDE, click the Help menu, then
  "Install New Software..."
- In the "Work with:" text box, insert
  the link provided by the site.
- In    the table presented below the
  text    box Vrapper should appear
  which a    checkbox next to it. 
  Check the    checkbox and click next.
- You should now be able to click the
  Finish button and the plugin should
  be installed.  You will probably be
  prompted to restart the IDE.  I would
  do so.
- Upon restart, there will probably be
  a vim icon on the toolbar that you
  can use to enable/disable the Vrapper
  plugin.  If there isn't, you should
  still be able to enable/disable it
  through Edit->Toggle Vrapper.

You may also want to check out http://eclim.org/ which rather than emulate Vim, allows it to be used directly with Eclipse in several ways.  I think Vrapper is probably closer to what you are looking for at the moment, but eclim might be useful to you in the future.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The plugin is also available (in Flash Builder CC (4.7)) via the Help/Eclipse Marketplace...